# How to get rid of collapsable icons in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, preferences

Does anyone know how to get rid of the [-] icons from Eclipse? I find them to be really distracting but I have no idea how to turn them off from preferences. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

click right on the numbers, go to folding and click on "enable folding". then the icons should be away.

[image]